# How to overwrite an existing image file in google colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am doing an ML project in google colab. I need to pre-process the whole image in the train set and replace those images with the newly preprocessed ones provided that train set images are already uploaded in "content/train/images/". I created an image_preprocessing function where the input is the image and returns preprocessed image. Now I need to save this image by replacing previous one.

This is my code :

```
import cv2
import glob
import os
path = "/content/train/images/*.jpg"
for file in glob.glob(path):
  img = cv2.imread(file)
  file_name = os.path.basename(file)
  img_preprocessed = image_preprocessing(img)
  with open(file, 'w') as f:
   f.write(img_preprocessed)
   print(file_name + " preprocessed and saved\n")
```

I am a newbie in python. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you have in your example is not too far but you are trying to save an image using a syntax made to write a text file (`with open(file, 'w) as f`).

As you are using openCV, you can directly save with `cv2.imwrite(file, img_preprocessed)`. All put together:

```
import cv2
import glob
import os
path = "/content/train/images/*.jpg"
for file in glob.glob(path):
  img = cv2.imread(file)
  file_name = os.path.basename(file)
  img_preprocessed = image_preprocessing(img)
  # Save the img_preprocessed as a picture with a path matching 'file'
  cv2.imwrite(file, img_preprocessed)
  print(file_name + " preprocessed and saved")
```

**NOTE:** This example will overwrite your original images as requested in the question. However, it may be an issue for repeatability, it may be better to save them in a `preprocessed_images` folder so you retain the source. But it may not be required, it is up to your usage.

Comment: I checked using imwrite but it is not overwriting. I don't know why. I run the code both in colab and locally in jupyter notebook. For both cases code is running, but when I check the images, image still remains the same. But img_preprocessed is different than source image. So I tried by imwrite to another folder location. Then it is saving preprocessed image in the new location.

Comment: That is weird, I ran it locally (and now on Colab) with cv2.resize() as my pre_processing and the image were overwritten. I can't really explain why it wouldn't in your case. You could try save using PIL (package named Pillow) `from PIL import Image` then `Image.fromarray(img_preprocessed).save(file)`. I don't see why it would be diferent though... If you do and it works for you, be aware that openCV use BGR channels so you need to convert to RGB before saving with PIL.

Comment: Thank you for the response. As you mentioned earlier I realized it is better to save preprocessed_images in a new location.

Comment: I have a doubt. my img_preprocessed is BGR image, now does imwrite store BGR image or RGB image ?

Comment: cv2 use BGR by default so if your image is BGR, cv2.imwrite would be good. I was just mentioning it in case you want to use PIL which is in RGB. Anyway, it is easy to confirm, just open one picture and if the colors are normal, everything is good :)

Comment: Now reading again your question, I realise I might not have answered it. The jpg file stored by cv2.imwrite is a regular RGB file. When you open it with cv2 it is stored in a numpy array in BGR and when you use imwrite it is converted again.

Comment: Thanks. Now it's clear